# Update Gnome on Ubuntu 16.04 after updating from Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: gnome

I followed the below info to install Gnome with a fresh Ubuntu 16.04 install on another computer. It worked. Now I need to come back to this one and bring this one up to spec.

I hope that I can install the new Gnome on top of this existing one after updating the 14.04 to 16.04 ? Then:
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-session-flashback
would work? And would preserve my settings?

If not, I guess I need to uninstall the existing Gnome before? or after? updating to 16.04. How would this be done? And I guess this would lose my settings?  (I have updated to 16.04 before, but had some problems and had to drop back by cloning my disk from a backup copy.)

Or maybe this existing Gnome has been updated all along?  How do I check the current version of Gnome on this machine, and what is the latest version?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
gnome-shell --version
```

Will display your Gnome current version.

Ubuntu 16.04 brings Gnome 3.18 by default. You're able to install gnome 3.20 via PPA.

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
 sudo apt update
 sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

It may break your theme and extensions.

Comment: I have Gnome Flashback installed on this new machine, and I get the  following result:
roger@roger-System-Product-Name:~$ gnome-shell --version
The program 'gnome-shell' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install gnome-shell
roger@roger-System-Product-Name:~$

Did I do something wrong?

Comment: Ups, I thought you had installed gnome-shell rather than gnome-flashback. Try with this command: gnome-session --version.

Comment: This is the original machine, the other one where I had to backtrack to a cloned disk copy.   It has Ubuntu 14.04, and Flashback.  It worked - roger@roger-desktop:~$ gnome-session --version
gnome-session 3.9.90

I'll be updating this one again in a few weeks.  I'm hoping it will carry this version of Flashback on to 16.04.  Last time that seemed to work until maybe I screwed it up trying to get Software Center back when now I think it was already there, just in a different place.